# Flow duration curve (fdc) extract low threshold

Tags: r

I am a newbie working with streamflow duration curves and the function `fdc`.
I am working with more than 300 series and I am interested in saving the low quartile threshold `Qlow.thr` value that appears in the plot generated:

[image]

Here is the reproducible example:

```
dat <- c(13.05, 90.29,  5.68, 49.13, 26.39, 15.06, 23.39, 17.98,  4.21,  2.51, 38.29,  8.57,  2.48 , 3.78, 18.09 ,15.16, 13.46,  8.69, 6.85, 11.97, 12.10,  9.87 ,21.89,  2.60  ,2.40, 27.40,  4.94, 83.17 ,12.10,  5.08 ,12.42,  6.19  ,3.60 ,32.58, 53.69, 38.49,3.61, 14.84, 34.48,  1.91, 21.79, 31.53,  6.70,  9.52, 22.64,  1.80 , 8.13, 10.60, 12.73,  4.17,  6.70 ,16.45)

fdc(dat,plot = T,lQ.thr=0.8,ylab='Hm3',main='Upstream monthly duration curve',thr.shw=TRUE)
```

The fdc function returns a vector of probabilities, but I am not sure how to convert these probabilities to the original units and select the 80% percentile value expressed in Hm3 as I would do with `pnorm`, for example, in case of working with normal probabilities.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914776/flow-duration-curve-using-facet-wrap-of-ggplot-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the FDC yourself by

```
dat <- c(13.05, 90.29,  5.68, 49.13, 26.39, 15.06, 23.39, 17.98,  
         4.21,  2.51, 38.29,  8.57,  2.48 , 3.78, 18.09 ,15.16,
         13.46,  8.69, 6.85, 11.97, 12.10,  9.87 ,21.89,  2.60,
         2.40, 27.40,  4.94, 83.17 ,12.10,  5.08 ,12.42,  6.19,
         3.60 ,32.58, 53.69, 38.49,3.61, 14.84, 34.48,  1.91, 
         21.79, 31.53,  6.70,  9.52, 22.64,  1.80 , 8.13, 10.60, 
         12.73,  4.17,  6.70 ,16.45)

dat <- sort(dat, decreasing = T)
df  <- data.frame(x = 100/length(dat) * 1:length(dat), y = dat)

plot(x = df$x, y = df$y, type = "l", log = "y")
```

[image: The plot created using <code>fdc</code> versus the one using <code>plot</code>]

So the sorted flow data is simply plotted against the percentage exceedance scale. This scale is created by dividing 100% by the number of data points which gives us the increment for each point.
Therefore

```
quantile(dat, p = c(0.2, 0.8), type = 1)
```

gives you your desired results.

Notice that the computation of the quantile differs in `fdc`. It seems like they just use

```
p <- c(0.8, 0.2)
dat[round(p * length(dat))]

> [1]  4.21 27.40
```

to compute the values.

Comment: Way simpler than what I got to do (modifying the original function to return the lQ). Although the q20 (4.356) slightly varies from the value given by the FDC function (4.21), the solution is great. Thank you so so much Martin.

Comment: I updated my answer. There are many ways to compute quantiles. The actual way used in `fdc` is added at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Very clear and didactic, thank you so much once again Martin.