# Plotting the duration of exceedances of a pollutant standard in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series

I have a data frame with a Date column and a column of calculated concentrations of a parameter. I am trying to plot a time-series plot that has scatter points of all the concentrations and then have a horizontal line showing the standard of the pollutant(which is 500). I can do this no problem. The problem I am having is trying to plot a line showing the duration of the exceedances > 500. I can't seem to find anything to solve my question. I would appreciate any guidance.

**Sample Data:**

```
df<-structure(list(Date_Time = structure(c(1480093200, 1482660000, 
1395651343, 1329823800, 1326929400, 1331233200, 1490130000, 1476138600, 
1474070400, 1489393800, 1483272000, 1393515068, 1480471200, 1332680400, 
1471226400, 1470853800, 1396124591, 1496250000, 1394581991, 1438177553, 
1332108000, 1493051400, 1475949600, 1491024600, 1488832200, 1473697800, 
1475404200, 1488511800, 1490212800, 1477040400, 1494793740, 1389346885, 
1473933600, 1390611191, 1486551600, 1476475200, 1473593400, 1388854543, 
1327012200, 1493611140), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Calculated_TDS = c(271.3692, 634.3604, 634.246, 219.546, 
    674.286, 169.21, 506.118, 452.6932, 314.8412, 4640.3052, 
    358.0844, 734.918, 97.71, 460.358, 385.998, 283.9532, 370.554, 
    309.2356, 296.766, 137.079616, 24.494, 383.996, 321.2476, 
    784.6248, 642.1396, 1320.7032, 213.254, 462.1884, 547.6452, 
    376.274, 195.1216, 595.35, 320.1608, 411.166, 882.5512, 288.5292, 
    533.574, 1000.326, 124.022, 256.6116)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Date_Time", 
"Calculated_TDS"))
```

**Code:**

```
library(tidyverse)

test_df<-df%>%
    mutate(greater = Calculated_TDS > 500)%>%
    group_by(Date_Time,Calculated_TDS)%>%
    summarize(n_greater = sum(greater), duration = length(Date_Time))


plot<-ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = test_df , aes(x = Date_Time, y = Calculated_TDS))+
  geom_line(data= test_df,aes(x=Date_Time, y = duration),stat="identity")+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 500,color="red"),size=1.3)

plot
```

I know what I have doesn't make sense but I don't understand how to find the duration of exceedances.

[image]

Comment: FYI, you code didn't run. Can you draw your expected output in Paint or Word?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to flow duration curve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831687/flow-duration-curve-fdc-extract-low-threshold

Comment: @Tung fixed code sorry, should work now. That's not quite what I want. I will try to draw expected output

Comment: @Tung I included expected output. The lines should be the time duration of each event that went over the standard of 500.

Comment: Can you pls define for us what an "event" is? Let's say a reading is over 500, as is the case about 35% of the time in your sample. When should the duration start and when should it end? As long as the readings continue to be over 500? In your drawing it looks like there is grouping that includes readings before and after the > 500 readings.

Comment: @JonSpring so an event would start at 500 and then end when it isn't 500 anymore. So the time duration of how long the exceedance lasts for. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Lavers' answer is a good one. An alternative approach is to make groups for your `geom_line` and subset data within that `geom`.

```
test_df$group <- paste0("Group_", cumsum(c(1, diff(test_df$n_greater) != 0)))
test_df$duration <- ifelse(test_df$n_greater == 1, diff(test_df$Date_Time), 0)

# A tibble: 40 x 5
# Groups:   Date_Time [?]
   Date_Time           Calculated_TDS n_greater duration group  
   <dttm>                       <dbl>     <int>    <dbl> <chr>  
 1 2012-01-18 23:30:00          674.          1      23  Group_1
 2 2012-01-19 22:30:00          124.          0       0  Group_2
 3 2012-02-21 11:30:00          220.          0       0  Group_2
 4 2012-03-08 19:00:00          169.          0       0  Group_2
 5 2012-03-18 22:00:00           24.5         0       0  Group_2
 6 2012-03-25 13:00:00          460.          0       0  Group_2
 7 2014-01-04 16:55:43         1000.          1     137. Group_3
 8 2014-01-10 09:41:25          595.          1     351. Group_3
 9 2014-01-25 00:53:11          411.          0       0  Group_4
10 2014-02-27 15:31:08          735.          1     296. Group_5
# ... with 30 more rows

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = test_df , aes(x = Date_Time, y = Calculated_TDS))+
  geom_line(data = subset(test_df, Calculated_TDS > 500), aes(x=Date_Time, y = Calculated_TDS, group = group), stat="identity")+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 500,color="red"),size=1.3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is there a way to make a new column saying how long each exceedance lasted?

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure what you want, but here is a starting point. The idea is simply to make columns for the exceeded and the below, filled with NA, and then plot.
Color assigned is red to the the exceeded line and blue to the below points. Note that the `color = "red"` should be outside the `aes` for the horizontal line. Only use color inside `aes` when the color should vary with the value.

library(tidyverse)

```r
test_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(greater = Calculated_TDS > 500, 
         exceed_value = if_else(greater, Calculated_TDS, as.numeric(NA)), 
         below_value = if_else(greater, as.numeric(NA), Calculated_TDS))

plot <- ggplot(data = test_df, aes(x = Date_Time)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = exceed_value),  color = "red") + 
  geom_point(aes(y = below_value), color = "blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = exceed_value), 
  color = "red") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 500), color = "red", size = 1.3)

print(plot)
#> Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x): unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018g.1.0/
#> zoneinfo/America/New_York'
#> Warning: Removed 26 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 14 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to get how long each event lasted in a new column?